# Distance from ships to coastline in nautical miles

Tags: python, distance, geopandas

I am trying to calculate shortest distance from any ship position to coastline in nautical miles using [this zip file](https://mapcruzin.com/panama-shapefiles/panama_coastline.zip).

I have tried using `GeoPandas`, `shapely`, `geopy` but I have not found a way that properly works. I tried using below code to spot the nearest point and then calculate the distance, but it's always reading the wrong `linestring`. I appreciate any help.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoSeries
from shapely.geometry import Point
p1=GeoSeries(Point(8.41655010639208, -83.11475151369626))
coastline=gpd.read_file('/Users/Danilo/Documents/Python/panama_coastline/panama_coastline.shp')
coastline=coastline[coastline['NATURAL']=='shoreline']
coastline=coastline['geometry']
coastline.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
#coastline.geom_type
#coastline
#p1=Point(8.41655010639208, -83.11475151369626)
#coastline.to_crs(epsg=5368,inplace=True)
#coastline.crs
#coastline.geometry.distance(p1).min()
line=coastline[p1.distance(coastline)==p1.distance(coastline).min()]
line.reset_index
#type(ls1)
#line.geom_type
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
p=nearest_points(p1,line[0])
from geopy.distance import geodesic, Point
p0=Point(p[0].y,p[0].x)
p1=Point(p1.y,p1.x)
geodesic(p0,p1).nautical
coastline.plot()
p0
#geodesic(Point(8.41655010639208, -83.11475151369626),Point(8.41388, -83.11114)).nautical
coastline[0].distance(p1)
```

---

Comment: Say the coastline is defined by 5 points, [A,B,C,D,E], should it return the GPS point in the middle of (A,B) if that is the closest?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly the problem is, but here is a basic example that calculates the distance, and plots the points on the map.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
```

Data import

```
panama = gpd.read_file("panama_coastline/panama_coastline.shp")
```

I define function to get the closest line point. This is not optimal, and if you calculate +1M points you want to optimize this.

```
def closest_line(point, linestrings):
    return np.argmin( [p.distance(linestring) for linestring in  panama.geometry] )
```

With this we can define a point and test

```
p = Point(-80,9)

closest_linestring = panama.geometry[ closest_line(p, panama.geometry) ]

closest_point = nearest_points(p, closest_linestring)
```

And plot them both on a map

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 20))

_ = panama.plot(ax=ax)
_ = gpd.GeoDataFrame(closest_point, columns=['geometry']).plot(ax=ax,c='red')
```

---

Edit: Added example to calcuatel distance in Miles

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric

dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
points_as_floats = [ np.array([p.y, p.x]) for p in closest_point ]

EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES = 3960

haversine_distances = dist.pairwise(np.radians(points_as_floats), np.radians(points_as_floats) )
haversine_distances *= EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES

print( haversine_distances[0][1] )
```

Comment: and there is something else with the method, because I have not been able to calculate distance, I am getting the error **cannot unpack non-iterable Point object** when running: p1=closest_point[1]
p1.x
p0=Point(p1.y,p1.x)

from haversine import haversine, Unit

haversine(p1,p0,unit=Unit.NAUTICAL_MILES)

Comment: It that a error still preventing you to calculate the distance?

Comment: Actually this error is when I am trying to calculate the distance, I think it is because I am using haversine or geopy instead of shapely.

Comment: i added an example with sklearn, you can also use haversine. You need to approx the radius of the earth (around Panama?) to convert the haversine distances to miles

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!!!!!!! It works perfectly perfect!!! Thank you very much!!! I do not know how to say thank you again!!